# When to tell recruiter I want to work part time

Tags: applications, part-time

I currently work part-time, and am looking for another job which will also need to be part-time.  There are almost no part-time jobs advertised in my field (IT project management), so I have been applying for full-time roles and stating in my covering letter that I know it's a full-time role but I think I'm a good fit and I'd like to talk about how I could make it work part-time.  I also say that I want to explore all the options and am willing to be flexible.

I am not getting interviews, even for roles where I would expect to be a good candidate.  I suspect that being up front about wanting part-time work is putting me at a disadvantage in the sift.  **Would it be acceptable to apply for full-time roles and only raise that I want to work part time at interview (assuming I get one!)?**

The roles I am applying for are generally in universities and not-for-profits. 
 People I know who work for the organisations I am applying to all tell me that flexible working is common and it is very unusual for a request to go part-time to be turned down - *after you have been recruited to a full-time role*.  Some have suggested I work full-time for a few months then ask to reduce my hours, but I am uncomfortable with this ethically and with the risk and disruption to my childcare arrangements!

Comment: The short answer to your bolded question is no.

Comment: Applying for a full time role and asking if it's ok to make it part time instead is like applying for a driver's license then during the test asking if it's ok if you can use the license to fly a plane instead.

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be acceptable to apply for full-time roles and only raise
>   that I want to work part time at interview (assuming I get one!)?

I would suggest you look for a *full time gig that offers the flexibility you need*.  If I had a full time req for a role your qualified for, I am going to have a hard time hiring you part time.  Most likely I have ( as the hiring manager ) determined I need a full time person.

I could see more tele-work to allow for your child care arrangements, but I don't see any new full time gigs wanting part time folks.

Your **only other viable option** would be to only apply for roles that specifically state they are part time.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be acceptable to apply for full-time roles and only raise
>   that I want to work part time at interview (assuming I get one!)?

If you get an interview for a full time position, then they are most likely expecting you to work full time. Trying to convince them that you can do it in a part-time position may possibly make yourself look like a know-it-all. Also, if they hire you part time, they may have to hire another person part-time in order to get all of the work covered, which would be a hassle.

I would look for a full-time job that is flexible so you can take care of your childcare arrangements. It's not uncommon for people to leave work for an hour to accommodate children, as long as you either make up the hours or get the job done. However, being transparent in stating exactly what accommodations you need when interviewing is always best. If you are a good/perfect candidate for the company, they will work with you.